# flutter: wait for the splash-effect tap of a button card

Tags: flutter, button, time, splash-screen

I have a widget button that when clicking, the splash does not appear correctly when it is clicked since it goes directly to a route and is very fast, is it possible to give a time for the tap animation to be seen and then follow the route?

```html
Card(
 margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
 child: InkWell(onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/textvoice'),
 child: Text('hello')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onTap: () async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 600));
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/textvoice');
}
```

---

Comment: Typing directly without any ide, may have syntax error.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked perfect and faster for me

Answer (score 1):

**First, create a boolean variable for check animation.**

```dart
bool isLoading = false;
```

**And then you can try this:**

```dart
Card(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
  child: InkWell(
  onTap: () async {
    setState(() => isLoading = true);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    setState(() => isLoading = fasle);
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/textvoice');
  },
  child: Center(
        child: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('hello'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

**If you aren't sure to understand this, I'll give you full Stateful Widget**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: buildButton(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Card buildButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () async {
          setState(() => isLoading = true);
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
          setState(() => isLoading = true);
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/textvoice');
        },
        child: Center(
          child: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('hello'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid multiple unnecessary gestures (i.e. the user accidentally presses the button quickly two times causing the onTap callback to be invoked twice, thus Navigator pushes the Route twice on the stack), you should use a boolean flag (e.g. isTapped).
For example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isTapped = false;
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          if (!isTapped) {
            isTapped = true;
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 160));
            
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/textvoice');
            
            isTapped = false;
          }
        },
        child: const Text('delayed splash effect')
    );
  }
```